# Select a composite key, where max(column_value)

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, aggregation

Say I have the following:

```
  PART     SUBPART  QUANTITY
  -------- -------- -----------
  01       02                 2
  01       03                 3
  01       04                 4
  01       06                 3
  02       05                 7
  02       06                 6
  03       07                 6
  04       08                10
  04       09                11
...
```

For each `part` I need to identify the `subpart` with the max quantity.

My real example is a little bit more complex, I mean that there are not one, but 3 subpart columns (like a composite key). So I need to identify `part` each part the couples `subpart1`, `subpart2` and `subpart3`...

As database I use db2 for as400, but any examples are welcome.

I tried to do the following, but this does not work:

```
with T (PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SQ) AS 
       (SELECT PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SUM(QUANTITY)
        FROM MYTABLE 
        GROUP BY PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3)    
select PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3 
WHERE SQ = max(SQ)
from T
group by PART
```

Comment: Does db2 allow `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part, subpart1, subpart2, subpart3 ORDER BY quantity DESC) AS part_quantity_rank`?

Comment: I can suppose affirmative, according to http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsqlp%2Frbafyolap.htm

Comment: Yes, it does support ROW_NUMBER(), which is often a good choice if you do not want to report multiple records in the case of a tie.

Comment: In the edited example above, if the quantity for subpart 04 had only been 1, would you want to return both 03 and 05 for part 1?

Comment: 05 for part 1? does not exist... I need the max, one time per composite key(no repeats).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For each part I need the subpart that has the maximum quantity".  How about this?

```
select t.*
from mytable t join
     (select part, max(quantity) as maxq
      from t
      group by part
     ) m
     on m.part = t.part and m.maxq = t.quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume DB2 for AS400 doesn't support MAX OVER, i.e. Windowed Aggregate Functions?

Then it would be easy, otherwise you need a correlated subquery:

```
with T (PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SQ) AS 
       (SELECT PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SUM(QUANTITY)
        FROM MYTABLE 
        GROUP BY PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3)    
select PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3 
from T as t1
WHERE SQ = 
   (select max(SQ) from T as t2
    where t1.PART = t2.PART)
```

Edit:

This is a version using Windowed Aggregate Functions

```
with T (PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SQ, MAXSQ) AS 
       (SELECT PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SUM(QUANTITY),
            SUM(SUM(QUANTITY)) OVER (PARTITION BY PART)
        FROM MYTABLE 
        GROUP BY PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3)    
select PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3 
WHERE SQ = MAXSQ
from T
```

But this version of DB2 seems to support only rankings:

```
with T (PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SQ, rnk) AS 
       (SELECT PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3, SUM(QUANTITY),
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PART ORDER BY SUM(QUANTITY) DESC)
        FROM MYTABLE 
        GROUP BY PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3)    
select PART, SUBPART1, SUBPART2, SUBPART3 
WHERE rnk = 1
from T
```

Comment: according to http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsqlp%2Frbafyolap.htm, it should support it

Answer (score 0):

"For each part I need to identify the `subpart` having the max quantity."

```
SELECT part, subpart 
FROM table t1
RIGHT JOIN(
SELECT part, subpart, MAX(quantity)
FROM table 
GROUP BY part, subpart) t2 ON t1.part=t2.part AND t1.subpart=t2.subpart
```

In your example data `subpart` seems distinct, but you didn't said anything about it, so I'm guessing that `subpart` isn't unique for each `part` (it is possible that `subpart` takes the value `01` for many parts)

Comment: subpart is not distinct (can be the same for 2 parts)